# Is it possible to reformulate this equation in a quadratic form?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

Considering $s=\frac{\vec{a}^\top\vec{b}}{\vec{a}^\top\vec{d}}$ where all the variables are column vectors, Is it possible to reformulate it to a quadratic form in terms of $\vec{a}$?

The reason i like it to be quadratic is because it'd added to objective of a constrained quadratic optimization problem that i have to solve!

Comment: no. This is homogeneous, but degree zero. If you multiply $\vec{a}$ by scalar $t,$ there is no change in $s.$ In finite dimension, quadratic forms are always expressible as $a^T H a,$ where $a$ is your column vector, $H$ is a real symmetric matrix.

Comment: Ummm. How would it help you if there were some quadratic form involved?

Comment: I can reformulate it as $\frac{v^\top H_b v}{v^\top H_d v}$, but i think i cannot go beyond that point!

Comment: That's better, that is called a Rayleigh quotient;

Comment: Is your $H_d$ real, symmetric, and positive definite?

Comment: maybe $s^2$ as a ratio of quadratic forms $$s^2=\frac{\vec{a}^\top\vec{b}\vec{b}^\top\vec{a}}{\vec{a}^\top\vec{d}\vec{d}^\top\vec{a}}$$

Comment: @WillJagy yes $H$ is p.d since it is real non-zero and diagonal. BTW for Rayleigh quotient $H_d$ needs to be identity matrix! 
Anyway, wondering if this representation can help in solving a quadratic programming?

Comment: Bob, we can write $H_d = C^T C,$ where $C$ is invertible. One version of $C$ comes from Cholesky but there are many others. Then write $y = Cv,$ so $v = C^{-1} y,$ and you can rewrite your quotient as a Rayleigh quotient using $y$ instead of $v$

Comment: @WillJagy, Yes! nice trick! 
But now can i benefit from it in my QP problem when i have it as the additive term? I just read that Rayleigh quotient has a definite min value.
The issue is that my QP is constrained so  i cannot rely on closed-form solutions of its individual parts!